# Searchbox for listview not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Hi I am trying to create a searchbox that searches a ListView I managed to do just that and it works if I leave it to be searched only by username.As soon as I replace the username with a parameter the code does not work anymore.Here is my code:

```
string searchSelectBox = SearchSelectDropDown.SelectedItem.Text;

GetAllUsersFromDb.SelectCommand =
    "SELECT aspnet_Users.UserName, aspnet_Roles.RoleName, "
    + "aspnet_Membership.Email, aspnet_Membership.LastLoginDate "
    + "FROM aspnet_Users "
    + "INNER JOIN aspnet_UsersInRoles "
    + "ON aspnet_Users.UserId = aspnet_UsersInRoles.UserId "
    + "INNER JOIN aspnet_Roles "
    + "ON aspnet_UsersInRoles.RoleId = aspnet_Roles.RoleId "
    + "INNER JOIN aspnet_Membership "
    + "ON aspnet_Users.UserId = aspnet_Membership.UserId "
    + "WHERE @SelectField LiKE @Param";
GetAllUsersFromDb.SelectParameters.Clear();
GetAllUsersFromDb.SelectParameters.Add("SelectField" , searchSelectBox);
GetAllUsersFromDb.SelectParameters.Add("Param" , SearchBox.Text);
GetAllUsersFromDb.DataBind();
textListView.DataBind();
```

The values that the searchSelectBox can take are Username , Rolename and Email

If I replace the @SelectField with username and type a corect username the sear works but as it is it does not.

What is the problem here?

Comment: When you put a break point in there what is the value of SearchSelectDropDown.SelectedItem.Text?  How are the ListItems in that control added--hard coded?  dynamically added?

Comment: Shouldn't the where be something like: `WHERE UserName like @Param` -or- `WHERE UserName like @SelectField`.  You've got to compare something in the database with an input, not compare two inputs together.  Oh I see 'UserName' like @Param vs UserName like @Param

Comment: You cannot use parameters as column names. Parameters are only for data values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
string searchSelectBox = SearchSelectDropDown.SelectedItem.Text;

    GetAllUsersFromDb.SelectCommand =
       string.Format("SELECT aspnet_Users.UserName, aspnet_Roles.RoleName, 
                      aspnet_Membership.Email, aspnet_Membership.LastLoginDate 
                      FROM aspnet_Users 
                      INNER JOIN aspnet_UsersInRoles ON aspnet_Users.UserId = aspnet_UsersInRoles.UserId 
                      INNER JOIN aspnet_Roles ON aspnet_UsersInRoles.RoleId = aspnet_Roles.RoleId 
                      INNER JOIN aspnet_Membership ON aspnet_Users.UserId = aspnet_Membership.UserId 
                      WHERE {0} LiKE @Param", searchSelectBox);
    GetAllUsersFromDb.SelectParameters.Clear();

    GetAllUsersFromDb.SelectParameters.Add("Param" , SearchBox.Text);
    GetAllUsersFromDb.DataBind();
    textListView.DataBind();
```

Comment: Looks like it'd work, but I'd recommend making sure searchSelectBox is in the expected list of 3 strings to avoid SQL injection attacks...

Comment: Of course, you HAVE TO verify that the searchSelectBox is an expected value.